# Cannot convert value or type of items in Python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why isn't it possible to either change the type or the value of the list items?

```
a = ['3.465759','2.8797','9.23544']

for each in a:
    print(each)
    each = round(float(each),3) + 2    
print(a)
```

The result is

```
   ['3.465759', 2.8797, '9.23544']
```

Comment: ``[round(float(x), 3) + 2 for x in a]`` ?

Answer (score 2):

`each` is the loop variable which takes the next value in `a` in the next iteration. Store the converted value in another list.

```
a = ['3.465759','2.8797','9.23544']
b = []
for each in a:
    print(each)
    each = round(float(each),3) + 2    
    b.append(each)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
3.465759
2.8797
9.23544
[5.466, 4.88, 11.235]
```

OR

if you want to modify the list in place, then

```
a = ['3.465759','2.8797','9.23544']

for i in range(len(a)):
    each = a[i]
    print(each)
    each = round(float(each),3) + 2
    a[i] = each
print(a)
```

OR

using list comprehension

```
[round(float(each),3) + 2 for each in a]
```

Comment: Modifying a list in a loop is bad practice though

Comment: Yes, it is. I agree

Comment: @NicolasGervais Why do you think it is bad practice? The code is iterating over a range of indices and assigning new values to the list elements. The list itself doesn't change at all, since its length always remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

you did not change `a`, when you do the conversion, make sure to change the value: ie:

```
a = ['3.465759','2.8797','9.23544']
for i  in range(len(a)):
    each = a[i]
    print(each)
    each = round(float(each),3) + 2 
    a[i] = each   
print(a)
```

or

```
a = ['3.465759','2.8797','9.23544']
for i, each in enumerate(a):
    print(each)
    each = round(float(each),3) + 2 
    a[i] = each   
print(a)
```

```
3.465759
2.8797
9.23544
[5.466, 4.88, 11.235]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['3.465759','2.8797','9.23544']

result = []
for each in a:
    each = round(float(each),3) + 2  
    result.append(each)
print(result)

Output: [5.466, 4.88, 11.235]
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
a = ['3.465759','2.8797','9.23544']
float_list = list(map(float, a))
print(float_list)
```

Output:

```
[3.465759, 2.8797, 9.23544]
```